# Extension of a holomorphic function in the disc

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions

let $f$ be a continuos function in ${0<|z| \leq r} $ holomorphic in the inner and such that $f(z) $ is real for $|z|=r$. Prove that exist a function $g$ on $\mathbb{C} ^*$ such that $f(z) =g(z) $ for every z with $0<|z| \leq r$.

I have no idea how to extend f.  :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Schwarz reflection principle.

Comment: But i have to prove that is holomorphic in all C*

Comment: Yes, that's what you'll get after reflecting in $|z|=r$.